# obtener cifra con 2 decimales

Tags: java

como puedo obtener el resultado de una cifra que tiene varios decimales
a otra en donde se muestre la cifra solo con 2 decimales pero que los decimales se hayan redondeado

ejemplo tengo la cifra 2.1890625000000 y deseo obtener 2.19

con que función de la biblioteca Math lo puedo conseguir?

### código empleado:

```
 calculo_horass = Math.round(sueldo/240*1.5);
```

las variables son de tipo double

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que agregues tu código para poderte ayudar mas fácilmente.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808648/5215609

Answer (score 1):

Aquí un ejemplo donde se redondea el valor a dos decimales:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sueldo = 2.1890625000000;
        
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        
        double calculo_horass = (double) sueldo / 240 * 1.5;
        System.out.println(calculo_horass);
        System.out.println(df.format(calculo_horass));
    }
```

Aqui se muestra el resultado de los valores:

> 0.013681640625
>
> 0,01

Aquí mas información sobre como [Redondear decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)